# Windows Universal App Message Dialog with Progress Bar

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I have a progress bar user control that I would like to act like a MessageDialog so that it blocks the screen until the progress bar is 100%. Does anyone have a suggested way of doing this or a good example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the Callisto library with the Custom Dialog that mimics the MessageDialog behavior. Here is an example/reference: https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/wiki/CustomDialog

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand you are using UWP (Windows 10), then you can use ContentDialog. You can put any content in it, including the progress bar.